# Robocopy (without /l flag) running for hours making log file huge, but not actually copying anything

Tags: windows, command-line, robocopy

Here's my command:

> Robocopy C: C:\C_root /FP /BYTES /TEE /S /E /COPYALL /DCOPY:T /MOVE /Z
>   /ETA /XJ /R:2 /W:30 /XF pagefile.sys /XD  /LOG:C:\robocopy.log.

BTW, notice the /XD option above.  After that I had a few directories that I want to omit.  I showed these between angle brackets like this: (left angle bracket) a few dirs I wanted to exclude (right angle bracket).  Amongst these dirs was the C_root dir itself, so that it did not get into an "infinite" recursion.  (This part was stripped from the post because angle brackets apparently have a meta-meaning to superuser.com about hyperlinks.)

The command window this was running in listed a few "EXTRA" files then "hung".  By this, I mean no more output, no cmnd prompt, and if I tried to scroll it up, it would immediately scroll right back to the bottom.

After about six hours, it finally finished, although I never got a cmnd prompt back in the window I started it in.  DIR shows the log file at more than 1.3GB, but when I try to do a MORE on it, I get `"Cannot access file"`.  `C:\C_root` never grew larger.

Does anyone have an idea what is going on here?

Comment: What exactly should this command be doing? Do you start this in the root of `C:`? (you should specify `C:\ ` then) But shouldn't you exclude `C_root` itself because i think you get a loop. As i read it you move everything from `C:\ ` to `C:\C_root`. But that includes `C_root` itself. So that will be moved to `C:\C_root\C_root` etc. (or am i reading this wrong?)

Comment: Thanks for the response Rik.  You are right the way it was posted.  But please check out my edit to the post.  What I'm trying to do is get my personal dirs off of C:\ because windows crashed and said to run their troubleshooter.  I did, and after six reboots, said we can't fix it, but you have the option of reinstalling the OS with either saving your data or not! So, I'm going to choose save my data, but knowing MS, they mean ONLY saving "Documents" and "Downloads".  I'm trying to get my stuff off of C:\ (from a simple cmnd prompt) in the hope it won't get wiped out.  A last resort is xcopy!

Comment: I know `Robocopy` can be very picky about the way you specify the directories. You can check the following: if you put some files in the `C_Root` dir (may be anything) and use the `/L`-flag do you see the files in `C_Root` or are they skipped? If you see them then `C_Root` is not correctly excluded. BTW usually i make a [VHD](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx) before doing a re-install. You then have a .VHD-file with the complete HD which you can mount in Windows 7. (So depends if you have W7 and you need a lot of free space to do this)

Comment: Two other notes: 1) you can include bracket if you use the code option above the editor, the `{}`. It adds 4 spaces before the text and you can use anything within that block. 2) You could specify `C:\Users` to backup and after that `C:\xxxx` for any directory you want. BTW I wouldn't have used the `/MOVE` because now you may have a non-working system for sure. I hope you don't have a `C:\C_Root\C_Root\C_Root\C_Root\` now?